# how to change/update textview on User Interface in android application?

Tags: android, database, user-interface, firebase, real-time

I am new to android,

trying to create `TextView` on User Interface in my app, which I can update or change at any time or on regular intervals from `backend`.

**For example**:  Price of the product is `$100` and after some time/days it's `$120`

I want to display **updated** price and after that **previous price** on `real time basis` on users' display.

I am using **Firebase** as my database

How to update/change price from `backend` of android app? Do I need `admin panel` or `Android` and `Firebase` are efficient of doing that, or I have to learn some other language.

> Using Android Studio

Comment: There's lots of examples on Firebase site... Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried, but i think it is possible with

```
addValueEventListener
```

Sommeting like that :

```
       mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference();

        mFirebaseDatabase.child("price").setValue("100");
        mFirebaseDatabase.child("price").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               //TODO 
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to update a price in a Firebase database is to update it manually trough the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/). You can named it also an admin panel. If we are talking about a few products, this is the easiest option.

If you want to do it programmatically, this lines of code will help you:

```
DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
root.child("products").child(productId).child("price").setValue("10");
```

If you need to change the prices on a regular basis than you need to think to create a web app that can make your job easier. This can be even a simple website.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there everythig alright? Can i help you with other informations?